# How can I make this C# method more generic?

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
public partial class Client : ConfigItem
{
    public void ValidateForInsert(ASystem defaultSystem, IEnumerable<Client> currentConfig)
    {
        if (this.Source == defaultSystem.SystemName)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(AMessage);
        }
        if (SomeOtherValidation())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(AnOtherMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

It's going to exist on many different types, all of which inherit from CofigItem

All the code is identical, so I want to move it to the base class.
Except the parameters contain 
IEnumerable<*ThisClassesType*> currentConfig

If I put it in the base class with `IEnumerable<ConfigItem>`, I have to call it with:

`client.ValidateOnInsert(defaultSystem, currentConfig.Cast<ConfigItem>());`

Which seems a bit daft as types of things like `client` will *always* be based off of `ConfigItem`.

Is there anyway to put something like:

`public void ValidateOnInsert(ASystem system, IEnumerable<T> currentConfig) where T : ConfigItem`(?)

Or just any way of making that neat, tidy and not require duplicate code or lots of casting?

Thanks,

`J1M`

Comment: What's wrong with the generic option you have suggested? Are you getting errors?

Comment: But how would the inheriting class (Client) present that method as public void ValidateOnInsert(ASystem system, IEnumerable<Client> currentConfig)?

Comment: Ahh, now I understand your question...

Comment: Your code doesn't actually use `currentConfig` - why do you need it?

Comment: Oh, and what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Oh it does, I just chopped it all out to make it readable. You can pretty much just ignore everything IN the method. .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether or not this will work as you haven't shown any code using the input sequence, but this *may* work:

```
public void ValidateForInsert<T>(ASystem defaultSystem,
                                 IEnumerable<T> currentConfig)
    where T : ConfigItem
```

So that's a generic method taking a sequence of items of type `T`, where `T` must be `ConfigItem` or some type derived from it.

Comment: I was getting hung up on the derived classes exposing a more specialized method so that I didn't have to add `<derivedtype>` at the point of calling. Of course what I was forgetting is that the compiler infers the value of <T> from the types of the parameters! Thanks, J.